# Why does RGraph.js complain about negative values when I have more than a multiple of eight groups?

Tags: javascript, svg, rgraph

I am using [RGraph](https://www.rgraph.net/) to make a stacked bar graph based on [this example](https://www.rgraph.net/demos/svg-bar-100pc-stacked.html). When I have more than sixteen groups, I get this error:

> Error:  attribute width: A negative value is not valid.
>   ("-0.882352941176471")

I have also tried increasing the number of groups with [this similar graph](https://www.rgraph.net/demos/svg-bar-stacked2.html). With this one, I cannot have more than eight groups. Why is this happening? Could it be a limitation with RGraph?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening, because of how my div width was set to a narrow option than was needed in order to contain each bar. In order to fix this problem, I increased the width of the enclosing div.